# UI Acceleo Launcher Project fails

Tags: user-interface, eclipse-plugin, launcher, acceleo

I've followed this simple tutorial http://wiki.eclipse.org/Acceleo/Getting_Started to create an UI launcher...but when I finish and I make a right click on my uml model, I don't have the acceleo tag "Acceleo Model to Tex", so I'm unable to run the plugin...do you know how is it possible? 
I use th eclipse version 3.6.1 with topcased...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see only two ways for this popup menu not to show. The least likely is that the extension of your model does not match the "model file name filter" field from the "new UI project" wizard ("*.uml" by default). I do not think that this is your case, but thought I would mention it anyways.

What I think is the problem in your case is : this tutorial does not really explain to people who are not familiar with Eclipse plugins how to use the UI project. Namely : this new "UI project" is an Eclipse plugin. In order for the menu it contributes to show, you have to deploy the project as a plugin in your Eclipse. This can be done by exporting the project as a deployable plugin (right-click => Export => Deployable plug-ins and fragments) or by spawning a new Eclipse instance from the Eclipse that contains the project (Run => Run Configurations... => double click 'Eclipse Application' then hit "Run").

This last solution is preferred for plugins undergoing development as it allows you to change the plugin and simply spawn a new instance again in order for the changes to show ... however if you do not aim at developping Eclipse plugins, this might not be the best solution as it forces you to have two workspaces : one for the development of the plugin, another for the testing. The UML model on which you will generate code has to be in this "testing" workspace.

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply...which project I have to export?the project which contains the uml models or the acceleo modeule?I suppose the second one..I ve exported it, recreate the Ui launcher, but the situation is the same...

Comment: this is a screenshot of the situation..it migth helps..http://img01.imagecanon.com/img.php?view=8d017204e3c4d90102d33a4af4c421f6

Comment: You also have to install the deployable plugin in your Eclipse after exporting it. There is a more complete user guide on the obeonetwork if you can register, (notably, see http://docs.obeonetwork.com/topcased-days-2011 for a video displaying how to launch a new runtime (part 6, at 2:00)). As for the deployment of the plugin Stéphane had blogged about it on http://stephanebegaudeau.tumblr.com/post/4044822578/from-an-acceleo-code-generator-to-an-eclipse-plugin .

Comment: I've followed the guide of sthepane, but after that I don't know how I have to do...I've created a feaure project, an update site project..and then? i've also seen the youtube tutorial part 6...but I don't understand why it is related with my problem...thank you for the patience!At now I have made this steps:1)Create a normal project(which contains uml models). 2)Create a Acceleo Module file which contains the mtl files. 3) Export the plugin as you have said 4)Create a feature project 5) create an upddate site project

Comment: I've solved...the last step is simpy to install the updatesite project and all works...Last question :-) ...do you know how is it possible to create a button on the toolbar related to my plugin?thank you for your help!

Comment: This is more of a standard Eclipse development question :). If you're going to implement your own plugins, I'd suggest taking a look at the (very good!) tutorials that can be located on http://www.eclipse.org/articles/ . If I remember correctly, http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Your%20First%20Plug-in/YourFirstPlugin.html described how to create a button and link it to custom code.

Comment: Thanks...now I have another problem.. :-( Everytime I make a right click on the uml model, then appears the tag AcceleoModelToText, but I can't select another transformation...I've tried to create a new plugin, to uninstall the previous, but the trasformation seems to be in memory (I don't know where)...besides, if I update the old generateFiles, this change isn't propagate..so if I launch the Transformation by AcceleoModelToText tag, eclipse run the old mtl files...